# Word for someone who is hungry for power and control

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What do you call someone who's running after power and is hungry of controlling everything/everyone, all the time? Somehow like <s>a moderator</s> Darth Vader.

Comment: Presidential candidate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such a person (as Darth Vader, not an ELU moderator! :) would be called a...

> [**megalomaniac**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/megalomaniac) *- a person who has an obsessive desire for power*

The adjectival form *megalomaniacal* does occur, but it's nowhere near as common as the noun.

Comment: You better add the cite in text as well or @tchrist will be on you.

Comment: @bib: Meh. In the unlikely event the link gets broken, it would be easy to find again. And even if oxforddictionaries ceased to have an online presence, I'm sure there'd always be another dictionary with the same definition.

Answer (score 1):

1. *power-hungry*: what it says
2. *control freak*: someone who has a great desire or a compulsion to control things (including other people)
3. *power-hungry control freak*: 1 + 2